# Are fcmTokens and ID Tokens the same and how to verify them with Node.js as a cloud function?

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My app uses fcmTokens assigned to a user and stored in a Firestore document to keep track of app installations and logins. When a user logs out of the app I delete the fcmToken from the Firestore document and run `InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID`.

However when the user has bad internet 'InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID' is run again when the app starts the next time. The fcmToken in the Firestore document is not deleted in this case.
Theoretically I could also run a query in the app and search for this token in all of the Firestore user documents and delete it there but I rather would like to use cloud functions to check if the fcmTokens of a user are still valid. If not I want to delete them. I started writing the following cloud function but I am getting an error saying

> Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

I assume I am using the wrong function and fcmTokens are not the same as ID Tokens?
Is there a way to check for the validity of the fcmToken similar to how I check here for the (non existent) ID Token.
Or should I somehow use ID Tokens in general for managing device specific login? ( I'm using a Snapshot listener that listens for fcmToken changes and I am logging the user out when a specific fcmToken is deleted.)

Here is my cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

var userA_UID = ""

exports.checkFcmToken = functions.firestore.document('registeredUsers/{userA_UID}').onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {

  userA_UID = context.params.userA_UID;

  const userInfo = await admin.firestore().collection('registeredUsers').doc(userA_UID).get();

  const fcmTokens = userInfo.data()['fcmTokens'];

  if (fcmTokens !== undefined) {
    if (fcmTokens.length > 0) {
      for (let fcmToken of fcmTokens) {
        checkToken(fcmToken)
      }
    }
  }

  function checkToken(fcmToken) {

    //will delete token from document array if invalid

    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(fcmToken)
      .then((decodedToken) => {
        let uid = decodedToken.uid;
        console.log(uid)
        throw new Error('Error!')
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM tokens and ID tokens are quite different, and cannot be used interchangeably.

- Firebase Authentication ID tokens identify a user. This means that if the same user is signed in on two different devices, they have ID tokens that identify the same user.
- FCM tokens (also called Instance ID tokens) identify an application installation. If you have two tokens from two different devices, there is nothing that is shared between those tokens.

FCM tokens are opaque strings, and cannot be be verified without calling the FCM API.

When you send a message to an outdated token, the FCM API responds with a clear error message. The idiomatic way to keep your list of tokens clean is to handle this error message and remove the outdated token, as shown in this [example from the Cloud Functions repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L72-L88).

Comment: Just to clarify, if I have successfully used `InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID` to delete an instance ID token, the next time I am sending a notification to this user I check if the tokens are still valid, or give me errors like:  `invalid-registration-token` or `registration-token-not-registered`. And if I get an error I can safely delete those tokens?

Comment: That is correct: if you get one of those responses, the token isn't valid anymore, or the device with that token hasn't checked in with FCM servers in a long time (at least 90 days iirc), and will get a new token if it tries to use FCM again anyway.